# How to write a left join with many to many relationship

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-5

I have the following entities:

Entity: Department
DepartmentId (int)
Name (int)
SuperiorDepartmentId (int, foreign key to department entity)
DepartmentPermissions (ICollection)

Entity: DepartmentPermission
DepartmentId (int)
UserId (int)
Permission (String)
Departments (ICollection)

Entity: User
UserId (int)
Name (string)
DepartmentPermissions (ICollection)

I need to return in my query all of the departments (including the ones where the user don't have permission) and the name of the permission when the user has any.

**Department**

```
DepartmentId | Name | SuperiorDepartmentId
1 | Sales | null
2 | Internal Sales | 1
3 | Marketing | null
```

**DepartmentPermissions**

```
DepartmentId | User Id | Permission
1 | 2 | r
2 | 2 | rw
1 | 3 | rw
```

**User**

```
UserId | Name
1 | John
2 | Mary
3 | Paul
```

If I ask for the data for user Mary (id=2), we shoud have as result set:

```
DepartmentId | Name | SuperiorDepartmentId | Permission
1 | Sales | null | r
2 | Internal Sales | 1 | rw
3 | Marketing | null | null
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to presume the existence of a navigation property `Department.DepartmentPermissions`.

```
var query = from d in context.Departments
            select new { 
                         Department = d, 
                         Permissions = d.DepartmentPermissions
                                        .Where(dp => dp.UserId == 2)
                                        .Select(p => p.Permission)
                       };

var result = query.AsEnumerable()
                  .Select(x => 
                  new {
                        x.Department.DepartmentId,
                        x.Department.Name,
                        x.Department.SuperiorDepartmentId,
                        Permissions =
                          string.Join(", ", x.Permissions.DefaultIfEmpty("null")
                      }
```

First the raw data are collected (`query`), then the final results are composed in memory. The latter is done because EF won't allow `string.Join` in a LINQ query. Your data structure allows for more than one permission per user in one department, hence the `string.Join`.

If you're *absolutely* sure that there will always be one permission you can do

```
Permission = d.DepartmentPermissions.Where(dp => dp.UserId == 2)
              .Select(p => p.Permission)
              .FirstOrDefault()
```

in `query`, and your done.